# How can I use beautiful soup to get the current price of a stock on Google Finance?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following python code and the goal is to get the current price of this stock, which is $110.80.

```
import urlparse
import urllib2
import pdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

url = "https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=0001&ei=yF14VYC4F4Wd0ASb64CoCw"

def WebCrawl(url):
    htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    P = soup.find()
    print P

WebCrawl(url)
```

Now when I print `soup`, the number 110.80 actually appears in multiple places, for example:

`{u:"/finance?q=HKG:0001",name:"0001",cp:"-1.07",p:"110.80",cid:"164573760542896"}`

and

`<span id="ref_164573760542896_l">110.80</span>`

and

`<meta content="110.80" itemprop="price"/>`

**First question**: what is the right place within the html text to look for current price of this stock, since it seems like the price occurs in multiple areas within the html text ?

**Second Question**: what should I put in the `soup.find()` or `soup.find_all()` field **such that I can obtain the current price of this particular stock**. Can someone help me out here please ?

Comment: I am sorry about this. When I was looking at your answer,  I felt like I confused you. This is why I edited the question to help people to understand what I am trying to get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` will allow you to find a tag within the HTML DOM. For example, if you want the title of the website you can do something like, `bs.find("title")` and it will return the first instance of title. (Like: `<title>Some title here</title>`) You can also filter tags with certain attributes. A lot of websites have tons of divs, but if you want divs that have class type `red`, you could do: `bs.find('div', attrs={'class': 'red'})`. This will return the first `div` that has class type `red`. [Read the documentation for more detail.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

For this example, you could do something like this to obtain the stock price:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.google.com.hk/finance?q=0001&ei=yF14VYC4F4Wd0ASb64CoCw"

def WebCrawl(url):
    htmltext = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    p = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "ref_164573760542896_l"}).text
    print p

WebCrawl(url)
```

For the meta tag you can do:

```
p = soup.find("meta", attrs={"itemprop": "price"})
print p['content']
```

Comment: How about for the `<meta content="110.80" itemprop="price"/>` bit? Because ultimately, I may want to get the current price of a different stock and the `id` may be different in this case.

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much. So `meta` here is the tag name, and `content` and `itemprop` are the attributes.

Comment: exactly. and since you are wanting the `content` attribute value, you treat `p` like a dictionary and get the value at `content`..theres no real reason for it except thats how BS returns found values and thats how you access specific attribute values